# Present an activity after an event

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent, android-activity

I am new to Android and have a question about presenting an activity.

I am creating an Intent using the constructor `Intent(context, MyActivity::class.java)` and presenting it calling `startActivity(intent)`from an activity.
The problem is my Activity has a delay before displaying the first frame (it is Flutter if you are curious), and I have a method on the activity instance that notifies me when the first frame is ready, It is called `onFlutterUiDisplayed()`.

Is there a way to make the intent only be actually presented after the first frame callback has been called?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't you call startActivity(intent) in your listener's onFirstFrameDisplayed() ?

Comment: the activity that is going to be presented that has this callback, not the one I am starting from.

Comment: why do you need to call startActivity(intent) for an actvity already being resumed ?

Comment: What I actually need is, when I start the activity using the intent, I don't want the activity to be instantly presented, I am to have it shown only after it is ready. Idk if it is possible, I am new to Android and don't know the SDK.

Comment: @LeonardoSilva What do you mean by "ready"? If your activity doesn't do any UI blocking tasks, it should appear instantly. There is no native mechanism that you can apply to only show the activity when it's "ready".

Comment: The activity does not do any UI blocking tasks, when it is presented the first flutter frame is not available yet, it shows a white screen, the first frame is only available after the method call that I put in the question. I would like to have it presented only after this method is called.

Answer (score 0):

When your second activity goes to foreground, its `onResume()` method is called.

When this happens, your first activity's `onPause()` is called.

Check the official documentation to get a better understanding of activity's lifecyle on Android:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle